# How to redirect on URL to when changed manually URL nuxt 2

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

For example,

http://localhost:3000/space/apartment-281822
http://localhost:3000/space/{category}-{code}

I get api information through code

```
  asyncData({ $axios, params, error, redirect }) {
let newParam = params.slug.split("-")[1];
return $axios
    .$get(`/api/v1/site/residences/show/${newParam}`)
    .then((res) => {
      return { space: res.data };
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      
      error({ statusCode: 404, message: "not found" });
    });
```

},

When the name of the category in the url is changed manually, it will be redirected to the same state as the previous category

I tested through validate() but did not get any results

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "url is changed manually" and "same state"?  The category is not referenced by any means in your code so why would it cause any change in result?